# Sharepoint 2010 social block branding

Tags: sharepoint-2010, branding

I have to brand a Sharepoint2010 portal. There are 2 buttons on the top ("I like it" and "Tags") which have to be replaced with custom HTML and images. Images src is hardcoded in tags (instead of CSS).

My approach is to rewrite inner HTML using jQuery. Could you suggest a better way?

**EDIT**: Ok, seems like there are no other ways. If you wanna styling social buttons, get jQuery and use it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think re writing the innerHTML of the `ms-socialNotif-Container` div is the best solution here.

Comment: Rewrite using JavaScript? Or on server-side using c# somehow?

Comment: I will go for Javascript. jQuery as you said.

Answer (score 0):

Why not replace the source images with your images in the hive?